# oozie workflow shellAction

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I am trying to run a shell action in an oozie workflow with the shell script containing the following command:

```
.#!/bin/bash

hadoop fs -mkdir /user/mathon_k/shell_dir

.#echo "hello "
```

I get the following error:

```
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

Log

> 2014-03-28 15:11:31,951 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action
>   [0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state :
>   userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
>   2014-03-28 15:11:31,952 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@:start:]
>   [***0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
>   2014-03-28 15:11:31,952 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@:start:]
>   [***0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in
>   DB! 2014-03-28 15:11:32,027 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] Start
>   action [0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] with
>   user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0],
>   userRetryInterval [10] 2014-03-28 15:11:32,170 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellActionExecutor: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328]
>   credentials is null for the action 2014-03-28 15:11:32,669 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellActionExecutor: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] checking
>   action, external ID [job_201403280835_0020] status [RUNNING]
>   2014-03-28 15:11:32,772 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328]
>   [***0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328***]Action
>   status=RUNNING 2014-03-28 15:11:32,772 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328]
>   [***0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328***]Action
>   updated in DB! 2014-03-28 15:11:45,254 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.servlet.CallbackServlet: USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-]
>   APP[-] JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] callback
>   for action [0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328]
>   2014-03-28 15:11:45,332 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellActionExecutor: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] action
>   completed, external ID [job_201403280835_0020] 2014-03-28 15:11:45,358
>   WARN org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellActionExecutor:
>   USER[mathon_k] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] Launcher
>   ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain],
>   exit code [1] 2014-03-28 15:11:45,518 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionEndXCommand: USER[mathon_k] GROUP[-]
>   TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328] JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@oozie_20140328] ERROR is
>   considered as FAILED for SLA 2014-03-28 15:11:45,563 INFO
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@kill] Start action
>   [0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@kill] with user-retry state :
>   userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
>   2014-03-28 15:11:45,563 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@kill]
>   [***0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@kill***]Action status=DONE
>   2014-03-28 15:11:45,563 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[mathon_k]
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W]
>   ACTION[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@kill]
>   [***0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W@kill***]Action updated in DB!
>   2014-03-28 15:11:45,626 WARN
>   org.apache.oozie.command.coord.CoordActionUpdateXCommand:
>   USER[mathon_k] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[oo_20140328]
>   JOB[0000028-140328083804680-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command
>   precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null],
>   Error Code: E1100

But when i change the shell script to the following it works well.

```
.#!/bin/bash

.#hadoop fs -mkdir /user/mathon_k/shell_dir

echo "hello "
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mkdir - use [workflow HDFS action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action)

if you want to run the bash - seem like it work fine

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for you suggestions but i use the above shell script just to test BUT the actual script for my project is:

#/bin/bash 

#use today's date and time

day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
 
hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs://florplpl01:8020/user/mathon_k/$day

 
hadoop fs -mv hdfs://florplpl01:8020/user/mathon_k/workflow_mails hdfs://florplpl01:8020/user/mathon_k/$day

Comment: there is something for that - coordinator, set data set and more to generate those paths

Answer (score 0):

We also experienced issues with issuing hadoop shell commands in Oozie due to security issues. 
Which version Hadoop are you using? Which version oozie?

For starters, try to set HADOOP_USER_NAME to name of the user you want the hadoop command to execute with prior to executing it.

Comment: Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0   and    Oozie client build version: 3.3.0-cdh4.2.0

Comment: is there any way to declare this HADOOP_USER_NAME as a global variable in the oozie worflow? I just want to avoid duplicates for every shell actions I have

Thanks